# Why isn't fread reading in the correct integer?

Tags: c, file, struct

This question was just to clarify why the correct output(year) isn't being printed correctly, given the following code.

For future readers, the issue was that the fget() function read off a byte that was supposed to be a byte that belonged to year, causing the year to not be printed correctly.

Here is my code 
Car structure

```
      typedef struct carType Car;
struct carType {
   int vehicleID;
   char make[20];
   char model[20];
   int year;
   int mileage;
   double cost;
   Car *next;
};
```

Code to write to binary file

```
  void writeBinFile(Car *headPointer)
{
     char fileName[20];
     //prompt user for name of textfile to print to 
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    FILE *ftp;
    Car *start =  headPointer->next;
    ftp = fopen(fileName, "wb");
    char separator = '0';
    while(start != NULL)
    {
       //write out 1 cell of data, cell contains 4 bytes
        fwrite(&start->year,sizeof(int), 1, ftp);
        fwrite(start->make,sizeof(char), strlen(start->make), ftp);
        fwrite(&separator, sizeof(char), 1, ftp); 
        fwrite(start->model, sizeof(char), strlen(start->make), ftp);
        fwrite(&separator, sizeof(char), 1, ftp);
        fwrite(&start->cost, sizeof(float), 1, ftp);
        fwrite(&start->mileage, sizeof(float),1,ftp);
        fwrite(&start->vehicleID, sizeof(int), 1, ftp);
        start = start->next;
    }
    fclose(ftp);
}
```

And code to read in a binary file

```
   void readFromBinFile(Car *headPointer)
{
      char fileName[20];
     //prompt user for name of textfile to print to 
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    FILE *ftp;
    Car *previous =  headPointer;
    ftp = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    Car *current;

    //go until the end of file is reached
    int c;
    while((c = fget(ftp)) != EOF)
    {
            current = (Car *)malloc(sizeof(Car));
            previous->next = current;
             //program receives 1 cell, that cell contains 4 bytes
             fread(&current->year, sizeof(int),1,ftp);
             printf("%d\n",current->year);
             char make[25];
             int count = 0;
             char oneAtATime= 'a';
             while(oneAtATime != '0') 
             { 
                    fread(&oneAtATime, sizeof(char),1,ftp);
                   if(oneAtATime!='0')
                   {
                      make[count] = oneAtATime;
                        count++;
                   }
            } 
            make[count] = 0;
           strcpy(current->make, make);
             char model[25];
              count = 0;
              oneAtATime= 'a';
             while(oneAtATime != '0') 
             { 
                    fread(&oneAtATime, sizeof(char),1,ftp);
                   if(oneAtATime!='0')
                   {
                      model[count] = oneAtATime;
                        count++;
                   }
            } 
            model[count] = 0;
           strcpy(current->model, model);
           fread(&current->cost, sizeof(float),1, ftp);
           fread(&current->mileage, sizeof(int),1,ftp);
           fread(&current->vehicleID, sizeof(int),1,ftp);
         previous = previous->next;
    } 
    fclose(ftp);
}
```

Here is my data that I am trying to write/read from bin file.(loaded this from the read/write to text which works)

```
2014 Toyota Rav4 cost:$40000 mileage:3000, vehicleID:1
2014 Toyota Celica cost:$3220 mileage:2222, vehicleID:3
```

In the read binary method, I use this line of code for debugging purposes

```
   printf("%d\n",current->year);
```

Which should print 2014 in both instances. However when i try running the code, this is what gets printed

```
1275068423
1811939335
```

Is there something i am missing in my read and my write method that is causing the year to be so off?

Comment: You might consider writing a value that tells you how long the string to follow is so you can just read that many bytes.

Comment: You also might consider creating a simple test case that demonstrates exactly the problem you're having, as suggested in the "How to ask a good question" section of Stack Overflow.   In the process of doing that, you'll probably discover your error anyhows...

Comment: What is `fget()`? Looks like fake code. If it's meant to be `fgetc()`, then of course your next `fread()` is going to give you garbage, because you're trying to read at least one byte too far into the file. You don't write a character and then your `int`, you just write your `int`, so if you try to read a character and then read an `int`, it's not going to match up.

Comment: GreenAsJade, I tried to, with that print year

Comment: Was this a good edit?

Comment: it's too long for me to revise it, but the question itself is OK, despite the negative vote you got. it's just long and not alot of people will take a second look at it. anyway +1, but do try to take only the smallest example showing the problem next time

Comment: Yeah I keep the example shorter next time. Felt that you needed the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a logic error. The line

```
while((c = fgetc(ftp)) != EOF) // Assuming you meant to use fgetc not fget
```

reads the first character from `ftp` that is supposed to be part of the `current->year`. When you execute

```
         fread(&current->year, sizeof(int),1,ftp);
```

you are reading the wrong data. If `sizeof(int)` is `4` in your platform, you are picking up `3` bytes of data from the saved `year` and one byte from the saved `make`.

My suggestion to fix it:

```
int year;
while(1)
{
        if ( fread(&year, sizeof(int),1,ftp) != 1 )
        {
           // No more data to read.
           break;
        }

        current = (Car *)malloc(sizeof(Car));
        previous->next = current;

        current->year = year;

        // Proceed with reading the rest of the data.
        // Make sure you check the return value of every call
        // to `fread` before proceeding to the next line of code.
```

Comment: How do i suppose i fix this? I need the fgetc to check sure that the end of file is not reached.

Comment: That "check" is totally useless. What if the file ends half way through a line? You should be checking the return from *all* your file input functions.

Comment: but i need a loop to keep things running? Should i not have a while loop on the outside?

Comment: The presence or absence of a `while` loop has nothing to do with it. In or out of the loop, you should check the return from all your functions, because your file could end at any time. Because of what you're doing with `fgetc()`, in this case you're actually *causing* it to end in the middle of what you think a line is.

Comment: I agree with that idea but i think for this practice problem, we are free to assume that all the pieces will be there

Comment: You're not free to assume that if you write code which causes that assumption to be false. If you want to make your code much more difficult to debug, I suppose that's your own affair.

Comment: I need a while loop to repeat that sequence of creating a car, setting all of its fields. What condition do you suggest having inside that while loop, if not fgetc?

Comment: I get with what youre saying with fgetc getting a char from int. I need a condition inside that while loop though to make sure that the car sequence keeps going